# Is in smarty an equivalent for macros like in twig

Tags: php, macros, smarty, twig, template-engine

I've wondered if there is an equivalent for the macro function from twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html in smarty.

I don't want to use smarty plugins for that because I want be able to write these macros right into the templates.

The only thing I found was the template inheritance with `{block}` http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl, but I want to pass arguments too.

Is there any equivalent for that?

In my example I want to use this for html forms and inputs like

```
<input type="{$type}" name="{$name}" value="{$value} [...]>
```

`{$type}`, `{$name}`, and `{$value}` are the arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, Smarty 3 has the `{function}` tag which does exactly that: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl